# Make a button that get pressed for example every 5 min

Tags: android, button, time

How can I make a button that gets pressed automaticly for example every 5th minute? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want schedule an action every five minutes you can use a timetask o a handler

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.it/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html

If you want schedule with long delay (hours) You should use ad alarmmanager

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html